# Spring boot return JSONArray field of model as null

Tags: mysql, json, spring-boot

I have a `JSONArray` field in the object:

```
@Column(name = "_history", columnDefinition = "JSON")
@Convert(converter = JSONArrayConverter.class)
private JSONArray history;
```

and this is `JSONArrayConverter`:

```
@JsonSerialize
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class JSONArrayConverter implements AttributeConverter<JSONArray, String> {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JSONObjectConverter.class);

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(JSONArray array) {
        LOGGER.debug(array.toString());
        if (array == null)
            return new JSONArray().toString();
        String data = null;
        try {
            data = array.toString();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("JSON writing error", e);
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public JSONArray convertToEntityAttribute(String data) {
        if (_EMPTY.equals(data) || data == null || "[]".equals(data))
            return new JSONArray();
        JSONArray array = null;
        try {
            array = new JSONArray(data);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("JSON reading error", e);
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

The problem is when requesting the object from MySQL database(history is JSON column and has data), Spring boot returns it as null:

```
"history": {}
```

Comment: did you verify if the converter logic gets invoked? is the mapping working?

Comment: String data = null;   <-- seems like that is firing a little too often maybe?

Comment: @easleyfixed it's ok. I changed to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67849195/1240052 but not work

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-60</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

First, add the above repository to `pom.xml`. Then changed the codes to below:

```
@Column(name = "_history", columnDefinition = "json")
@Type(JsonType.class)
private List<Map<String, Object>> history = new ArrayList<>();
```

and everything works for me.